# ¿Cómo identificar en Python filas en un dataframe en el que un valor de una columna se contrarresta con ese mismo valor pero en negativo?

Tags: python

Tengo un Dataframe con n columnas en el que necesito identificar si existen filas (y cuáles son) que se contrarrestan porque existe el mismo valor en negativo.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {
   1: {'Código_recibo': 'n1', 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 70},
   2: {'Código_recibo': 'n2', 1: 15, 2: 25, 3: -70},
   3: {'Código_recibo': 'n3', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 70},
   4: {'Código_recibo': 'n4', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 30},
   5: {'Código_recibo': 'n5', 1: 12, 2: 22, 3: 35},
   6: {'Código_recibo': 'n6', 1: 13, 2: 22, 3: -35},
   7: {'Código_recibo': 'n7', 1: 14,        3: 45},
   8: {'Código_recibo': 'n8', 1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 55},
}
```

Necesito identificar una forma con la que saber que los códigos_recibo n1, n2 y n3 se machean porque la columna 3 el dato es igual pero en negativo (70, -70) y lo mismo n5 y n6.
He probado con lo siguiente pero no me vale:
`df = df.loc[~df['3'].isin(-df['3'])]`
También probé a cambiarlo a valor absoluto, pero no me sirve porque tengo que identificar el positivo y si tiene su valor negativo
¿Cuál es el objetivo? que cuando se introduce mal una cantidad de cobro, meten la misma cantidad en negativo para solucionarlo y cuando es en el mismo mes no pasa nada, pero si se hace al mes siguiente (cuando se dan cuenta), aparece un cobro un mes y un negativo el mes siguiente y desvirtúa.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: En este caso el nombre de tu columna no está coincidiendo. fijate en los datos que la columna llamada `3`, la estás referenciando así  `'3'`. Corrigiendo eso, y con el armado de tu df de esta forma: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')` debería ser suficiente, Pero sí lo que quieres hacer es solo mostrar los casos en los que esto sucede.. solamente deberías quitarle `~`.

Comment: Buen día, para entender mejor, las filas que deseas identificar deben ser `Inversos aditivos`. ¿Deben ser filas consecutivas o pueden estar en cualquier parte del `datafame`? Si tienes como en tu caso una fila con `-70` ¿Deseas obtener todas las filas con valor `70` o únicamente la primera coincidencia?

Comment: Debes hacer una búsqueda recursiva e ir eliminando los valores que no deseas